# morphing cvs sticky branch tags dont change added files

Tags: branch, addition, cvs

Quite often I will start coding a feature on our trunk (AKA HEAD) and after starting to change the code realize that I probably want to do this on a branch.  This is fairly easy to do, I simply create the branch with something like:

```
cvs rtag forkName all
cvs rtag -b branchName -r forkName all
```

Then from my modified workspace I morph it into the created branch:

```
cvs up -r branchName
```

The problem I'm having is that any file that has been added previously is not morphed over to the branch but remains "added" to the trunk.

To fix this, I've gone into the CVS/Entries file and appended the branch tag to the added file entries (don't try this without parental supervision kids).

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Since your CVS repository does not know about your new files, they keep being added to the trunk. If you would commit them using:

```
cvs commit -r branchName
```

they should get the branch tag and any further commits can be normal.

Comment: That's just it, the trunk is not ready for the new files yet.  All the other files get morphed over to the new branch, why shouldn't the added files as well.  The whole idea of a branch is to allow development to continue in such a way as to not impact the mainline product.